# How to make Flex Spark Label to be auto resized?

Tags: apache-flex, label, flex4, autosize, flex-spark

I'm creating the Label component like this

```
var label:Label = new Label();
label.text = "some text";
label.styleName = "someStyle";
addChild(label);
```

But it stay invisible until I explicit set the width and height.
How can I make the label to be auto resized according to it's text?

Comment: Resized how? Do you want it to wrap onto a second line? Keep everything on a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question [here](http://blog.grio.com/2009/10/wrangling-flex-labels-autosizing-text.html)
The solution is to call a measureText() function for the label

```
var lineMetrics:TextLineMetrics = label.measureText(label.text);
label.width = lineMetrics.width;
label.height = lineMetrics.height;
```

Comment: Works with my Spark labels.

Answer (score 3):

I've also noticed the above answer doesn't seem to work with spark components. This does however work for me.

label.width = label.measuredWidth;
label.height = label.measuredHeight;

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `label.percentWidth = 100;` to allow the label to automatically grow with the text. If you want it to stay on a single line, you'll also want to set the `maxDisplayedLines = 1;` property as well.

You may also want to use `addElement(label)` instead of `addChild(label)`.

Comment: That doesn't work, label remains invisible.
Besides that, how is setting the component's width to 100% make it auto resized?

Comment: It doesn't auto resize it per se, but sets the label's width to the width of its container. It might help if we could see some more of your code. You might also want to try calling `label.validateNow()` after adding the label to the container.